# Can we use witnesses generated by OpenSSL's Rabin-Miller primality test to help factorization?

Tags: rsa, openssl

If I have a 2048 bit value used as the modulus for an RSA exchange, and OpenSSL's BN_is_prime() has determined that that value is not a prime, does that mean that OpenSSL has found a strong Rabin-Miller witness?  If so, if we could get OpenSSL to output the witness(es), how might that help us in the factorization of the value?

Comment: Do you really mean Diffie-Hellman (which typically doesn't use specifically 'semiprime' values)?  Or, do you mean RSA?

Comment: I have updated the question to explicitly state RSA and remove the assertion that the key is semiprime.  I only know that OpenSSL's primality test says that the key is not a prime.

Comment: If you could factor integers that way, don't you think this would make factorization an easy problem?

Comment: I suppose it depends on your definition of 'easy'.  If you mean trivially easy, I'd be surprised if that were the case.  If you are being intentionally vague, then you're really just restating my question.  I want to know if having identified MR witnesses makes factorization easier by any non-trivial amount, and if so, how.

Comment: OpenSSL routinely makes Rabin-Miller tests on the factors of RSA keys that it generates; but for factors that end up used, these tests never conclude that the factor is composite. Are you asserting that OpenSSL makes Rabin-Miller tests on an RSA public modulus? If yes, what's the justification or source?

Comment: @fgrieu The OpenSSL documentation (see here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.1/crypto/BN_is_prime.html) says that BN_is_prime() performs a Miller-Rabin primality test in the input it is given.  I have opted to give it a number which just happens to be the public modulus in an RSA exchange.  It reports that the number is not a prime.  Here is the code to check for 'witness-ship': https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/bn/bn_prime.c#L385-L410

Comment: @namreeb: thanks for having clarified that you (not OpenSSL) decides to make the Miller-Rabin primality tests discussed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does that mean that OpenSSL has found a strong Rabin-Miller witness?

Yes, it does.

> if we could get OpenSSL to output the witness(es), how might that help us in the factorization of the value?

No, it wouldn't help; for most composite numbers, the vast majority of values are Rabin-Miller witnesses (it's provable that at least $\frac{3}{4}$ always are, but for most composites, the ratio is very close to 1).  By far the most frequent for the Rabin-Miller to claim compositeness is that the random value $x$ is a value for which $x^{n-1} \ne 1 \bmod n$ (and so you never hit a 1 or a -1 in the sequence); such a value $x$ proves that $n$ is not prime, but gives no indication of the factorization of $n$.  Now, if you found an $x$ for which you fail for the other reason; because Rabin-Miller hit a 1 without hitting a -1 first, such an $x$ would immediately yield a factorization.  However, such values of $x$ occur only extremely rarely in practice.